# Trying to write update query containing ampersand value in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i am trying to write update query containing  ampersand  value in asp.net c# but it insert value with '' . i want the

value in textbox 'txtBxDepNam' is "Mechanical Maintenance - M&U" i want to update same value in table T_DEC_DEPTCD_DEPT  and tried as given below  but the issue is  value is not saved as
"Mechanical Maintenance - M&U" rather it is saved as Mechanical Maintenance - M'||'&'||'U

//checking & value in textbox

```
if (txtBxDepNam.Text.Contains("&"))
                    {
                        string newdepname = txtBxDepNam.Text.Replace("&", "'||'&'||'");
                        objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME = newdepname;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME = txtBxDepNam.Text;
                    }
                    
                    objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_CD = ddlistApprovers.SelectedValue;
                    objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME1 = ViewState["DepName"].ToString();

int rowsAffected = objDecDiscussBLL.addModifyDepName(objDecDiscuss, Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_ID].ToString());



//Bind the ON parameters.
            objConn.AddParameters(":DDD_DEPT_NAME", objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME);
            objConn.AddParameters(":DDD_DEPT_CD", objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_CD);
            objConn.AddParameters(":DDD_DEPT_NAME1", objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME1);

public const string strInsertUpdateDeleteDepName = "UPDATE T_DEC_DEPTCD_DEPT SET DDD_DEPT_NAME=:DDD_DEPT_NAME  where DDD_DEPT_CD=:DDD_DEPT_CD and DDD_DEPT_NAME=:DDD_DEPT_NAME1";
```

Any idea would be appreciated .

Comment: Stop doing `string newdepname = txtBxDepNam.Text.Replace("&", "'||'&'||'")`.

Comment: @mjwills how to do could you suggest please.

Comment: @Shivam: By removing that line of code.  Any line of code or operation that you don't want to perform, simply remove it.

Comment: @David any example ,please suggest

Comment: @Shivam: If you're not familiar with *how to edit the code* (such as in Visual Studio or even just a text editor and then re-compiling) then there isn't much anybody can do here to help you.  Now would be a good time to either talk to whoever gave you this code or start with some introductory tutorials on writing code in C#, specifically one which covers how to open Visual Studio, edit the code, and compile it.

Comment: **Literally** remove `.Replace("&", "'||'&'||'")`.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the first if and only keep the content of the else.

```cs
if (txtBxDepNam.Text.Contains("&"))
                    {
                        string newdepname = txtBxDepNam.Text.Replace("&", "'||'&'||'");
                        objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME = newdepname;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME = txtBxDepNam.Text;
                    }
```

becomes

```cs
                    objDecDiscuss.DDD_DEPT_NAME = txtBxDepNam.Text;
```

I guess that this if was inserted as a way to escape the `&` to something safe for the database. This is something that is often used with the quote (`'`) to avoid SQL injection. But in your case, you seem to already be using database parameters, and thus has no need for this type of escaping.